# Where is the battery location of Eviation's new electric aircraft Alice?

Tags: battery, electric-aircraft

Where is the battery situated on Eviation's new electric aircraft Alice which has two fuselage-mounted electric propulsion systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to FlightGlobal](https://www.flightglobal.com/airframers/eviation-alice-fire-involved-lithium-ion-batteries-which-ignited-after-hours-of-powerplant-tests/141228.article) the batteries of the original prototype were located in the fuselage, under the floor structure:

> He [engineer Jonathan Johnson] got out of his seat and went to the battery box. He felt the box, noticing it was getting hot, then he turned back and noticed gray smoke coming from under his seat,” says the inspector’s report. “Johnson called out, ‘Smoke, smoke, smoke’, and then, ‘Get out, get out, get out.’”

The new prototype, which is of a different design in many aspects, is not yet built. Renderings portray a plane with similarly slim wing profiles with regards to the burned down prototype, so one can assume the batteries will be inside the fuselage.